# resetting serial port configuration

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

**stty** allows to read a serial port configuration. I have noticed that when some program opens, configures and later closes a serial port the last serial port configuration is still present in the system. When it reset to the defaults ? Only during reboot ?

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux **;-)** Could you please [edit] your question and provide a bit more info on what you want to do exactly? The answer to "When" is indeed "When no programs are using stty"...

Comment: This question has been altered by Goro from what the original questioner actually asked, which was not when _can_ it be reset but when _is_ it reset.  Goro also introduced the erroneous division of the second sentence in twain.

Comment: @JdeBP that's quite outrageous, and it's not the [first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/469426/revisions) [time] (https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5000/undoing-an-edit-by-someone-else). Can something be done about it?

Comment: Is the serial port removable, for example is it a device that you're plugging into a USB  port?

Answer (score 2):

The serial port configuration will take the default values after a reboot as you mention, you can reset some of the default parameters values by using `stty sane`, you need to indicate the device using `-F`:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 sane
```

Use `stty --help` to see the list of affected parameters for `sane`.